# Laravel retrieving element from input array

Tags: php, laravel, request

I got a hidden field with that contains a match variable.

```
{{ Form::input('hidden', 'match', $match, ['id' => 'match']) }}
```

How can I retrieve the 'home' field etc in my store method?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info($request->match);

        Ticket::create([
            'home' => $request->match->home,
            'away' => $request->away,
            'place' => $request->place,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'section' => $request->section,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'competition' =>  $request->competition
        ]);

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show us the `Log::info($request->match);`? Is it an object? Array?

Comment: I assume you're storing the match id in the hidden field,  simply query for it in your controller with `Match::find($request->match)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as you have it now will not work.

```
{{ Form::input('hidden', 'match', $match, ['id' => 'match']) }}
```

Will have a string stored in it. In your Controller function you are trying to acces a object parameter `$request->match->home`. The only way to do something like this is to work with json_encoding/json_decoding. Where `$match` should be json_encode object and `$request->match` should be decode in your Controller.

Possible solution:

```
//in your blade file
{{ Form::input('hidden', 'match', json_encode($match), ['id' => 'match']) }}

//in your controller
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $match = json_decode($request->match);

    Ticket::create([
        'home' => match->home,
        'away' => $request->away,
        'place' => $request->place,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'section' => $request->section,
        'amount' => $request->amount,
        'competition' =>  $request->competition
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

If you do not like the solution of using php code in your blade file an even better solution would be to Serialize your Match object:

```
$match= App\Match::find(1);

$match = $match->toJson();
return view('edit', ['match' => $match])
```

Comment: using json to encode and decode did the work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store a encoded json string in your input:

`{{ Form::input('hidden', 'match', $match, json_encode(['some' => 'thing'])) }}`

You will need to decode it again:

`$match = json_decode($request->match)`

Then you can:

`$match['some'];`